# Two factory class to generate different interface instances with same condtion

Tags: java, oop, object, design-patterns

Java Program

```
enum FILE_TYPE {
    XML, JSON;
}

interface Parser {
    void parse();
}
class XMLparser implements Parser {
    public void parse() { }
}
class JSONparser implements Parser {
    public void parse() { }
}

interface Mapper {
    void map();
}
class XMLmapper implements Mapper {
    public void map() { }
}
class JSONmapper implements Mapper {
    public void map() { }
}

class ParserFactory {
    public static Parser getInstance(FILE_TYPE fileType) {
        switch(fileType) {
        case XML:
            return new XMLparser();
        case JSON:
            return new JSONparser();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class MapperFactory {
    public static Mapper getInstance(FILE_TYPE fileType) {
        switch(fileType) {
        case XML:
            return new XMLmapper();
        case JSON:
            return new JSONmapper();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In above java program both factory method generate different interface instance depends on same condition here, i,e both uses same enum FILE_TYPE.

Is it right to use two factory method for this case?
constraint is i can't combine both interface into one.

I am very new to java design, Kindly help me

Comment: Your naming is completely contrary to Java convention. Classes are **always** is `PascalCase`; `camelCase` is reserved for variables. `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE` is reserved for compile time constants. Please update your code accordingly.

Comment: As to the actual question; I would suggest you create an `interface ParserMapper` or similar with `getParser` and `getMapper` methods. Have your factory return a `ParserMapper` - that is unless there is any reason to ever use an `XmlMapper` with a `JsonParser`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider You are right but the idea is parser alone will be reused by other module so i separated both.

Comment: Then pass `parserMapper.getParser` to that module. What's the problem?!

Comment: `enum FILE_TYPE` - this name is still wrong. See `getInstance(FILE_TYPE fileType)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Mapper implementation would be very huge so i don't want to provide the implementation to the other module. could you pls provide the sample code, if my understanding was wrong

Comment: @sujin  "but the idea is parser alone will be reused by other module " So having 2 distinct interfaces and 2 distinct factories is required. Why gathering things that you want to separate ?

Comment: @davidxxx i just take this parser and mapper as an example but in actual production code both are different funtionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, your current design is incorrect.

Your code is clearly violating **[open closed principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416476/is-the-open-closed-principle-a-good-idea)** i.e., you will end up with **`switch` statements at too many places**, which is NOT a good design because if you wanted to add HTML parser (or some other parser later), you need to add the `switch` statements into two `Factory` classes.

The solution is you need to use abstract factory pattern as shown below:

```
interface ContentHandler {
     public void parse();
     public void map();
}


public class XMLContentHandler implements ContentHandler {

    public void parse() { }

    public void map() { }
}


public class JSONContentHandler implements ContentHandler {

    public void parse() { }

    public void map() { }
}

class ContentFactory {
    public static ContentHandler getInstance(FILE_TYPE fileType) {
        switch(fileType) {
        case XML:
            return new XMLContentHandler();
        case JSON:
            return new JSONContentHandler();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

> I don't want to share the mapper implementation to the system which
>   reusing the parser.

`Parsing` and `Mapping` responsibilities should be handled by their own classes (like `XMLParser`, `XMLMapper`, `JSonParser`, etc..) as shown below, which would then complied to [single responsibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620022/example-of-single-responsibility-principle) principle.

```
public class XMLContentHandler implements ContentHandler {

        @Inject
        private XMLParser xmlParser;

        @Inject
        private XMLMapper xmlMapper;


        public void parse() { 
            xmlParser.parse();
        }

        public void map() { 
            xmlMapper.map();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this parser will be reused by other modules in the system. mapper implementation would be very huge so i don't want to share the mapper implementation to the system which reusing the parser.

Comment: I suggest inject `XMLMapperImpl` and `XMLParserImpl` to the above `XMLHandler` and the responsibilities are separate then. Similarly for JSon

Comment: i am very new new object oriented design, could you please give me a small code sample

Comment: Code sample added above