# JustMock vs. TypeMock vs. Other

Tags: .net, unit-testing, telerik, typemock, justmock

With Telerik's JustMock product newly available, it has a lot of similarities to TypeMock, in the ability to mock concrete classes, not just abstract classes or interfaces.  I was just curious your opinion on one or both of the products.  What do you like or dislike?

Seems like JustMock might be shy on some of the features (TypeMock has been around for a while), but it had some good features.  Or if you have any others you feel are similar in features.

Comment: [rhino-mock-vs-typemock-vs-justmock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637066/rhino-mock-vs-typemock-vs-justmock-vs?lq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just use JustMock since a couple of days and one of the greatest features that I have found is that JustMock let the "Edit and continue" of Visual Studio work instead of TypeMock that lock totally your code like with the old version of visual studio; 2001-2003. In TypeMock forum, there is a post since 2008 and no work around has been found except that changing value of variable but not the code itself.

For me, this is a huge advantage because I like to changed code at runtime and I don't want my Visual Studio 2010 returns to the dark old days.