# Has nUnit got a mocking framework built in and should I use it?

Tags: .net, nunit, mocking, nunit-mocks

I recall that there is a mocking framework **build into** nUnit, but I can find details of it on the nUnit web site.   **Was I dreaming?**

I was considering using it to save the pain of having to introduce another assembly that we will have to managed on all developer’s machines.

**Are there any great dis-advantages to it as a mocking framework?**

Comment: I think you might be right http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379230/rhinomock-vs-typemock-vs-nunits-mocking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have found:

nUnit mock is in its own dll (nunit.mocks.dll) so it not truly built into nUnit – this removes the reason I was looking at it.

From another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379230/rhinomock-vs-typemock-vs-nunits-mocking/1380126#1380126):

> NUnit Mocks is very quaint as far as
>   mocking goes. It doesn't support the
>   currently preferred Arrange-Act-Assert
>   syntax relying instead on
>   Expect-Verify (record/replay). It also
>   relies on **strings to identify method
>   and property names** instead of lambdas.
>   This makes it significantly resistant
>   to refactoring. This is a serious
>   problem. I would not recommend it.

So I think nUnit.mock is a none-starter for new code.

Answer (score 2):

It seams to use [strings](http://www.zorched.net/2007/03/10/mocking-net-objects-with-nunit/) rather than method calls. I'd avoid like the plague, string based mocking frameworks don't handle refactoring well (and generally suck). It is also [not being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884040/where-is-the-nunit-mocks-documentation).

> introduce another assembly

Throw it in the version control. :)